# FIRE. Checking if a list of rectangles collides with a player rectangle

Tags: python, pygame

I know i need a loop to check if a list of bullets hits a player.
I've tried researching online for 2 hours for reference code but all use sprites and classes.

```
#Bullet Collision with players

for i in range(len(bullets_2)):
 #player is a rectangle style object
    if bullets_2[i].colliderect(player):
        player_health -= 10
```

Sadly enough my computer science teacher hasn't taught the class about sprites or classes, so let's avoid that.

I tried having the code above check if the list collides with the rectangle player.

The point of the above code is for the game to to take health away from the health bar if the enemy player's bullets hit the player.

## EDIT:

I only have about 8 days to finish this game

## TLDR:

How do I check to see if a list collides with a rectangle.

Comment: _"Sadly enough my computer science teacher hasn't taught the class about sprites or classes, so let's avoid that. "_ - But that doesn't mean you cannot learn it and be ahead of your class :-) I gave a bit of an overview of how to make and use sprites [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38933399/how-to-make-your-character-move-without-tapping-repeatedly-on-buttons/38935542#38935542). I know you may not want to learn how to use sprites, but in the long run they will be much, _much_ more convenient to use than plain shapes.

Comment: Oops my bad. Forgot to mention I only have less than a week to finish this game. And I'm kind of tight on time.

Comment: https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidelist or https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidelistall but for this you'll prob need a list of all bullet rects. better use collidelistall which returns a list of all rects which intersect with a given rect as opposed to collidelist which only returns the index of first intersecting rect

Comment: The code you've posted should work (if it doesn't you have to post an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), but you have to remove the bullets from the list after they've collided or they'll subtract 10 hp from the player each frame. Keep in mind that you shouldn't modify lists or other iterables while you're iterating/looping over them and rather create a new, filtered list.

Comment: @GLaDOS I tried collidelistall but I get an error "Trace back Error (most recent call) Argument must be a sequence of rect style objects". I want to check for collision for both players seperately.  #Bullet Collision with players

for i in range(len(bullets_2)):
 #player is a rectangle style object
    if bullets_2[i].colliderect(player):
        player_health -= 10

Comment: Post your `bullets_2` list and the `player`. [We need to see the code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you want more help.

Comment: As @ChristianDean puts it, using sprites is always going to be a better option. Or else, you have to manually move and check for collision of each bullet rect with the player rect. Now to your error.. colliderect takes a list of rect arguments. It needs [player.get_rect()]. Change it and the code would be legal but still it won't work as you are blitting player custom (x,y) pair and not using rect (so the rects are always gonna be const.. try printing it and u'll see). Look the code I posted below. It's using sprites tho.

Answer (score 0):

As in the comment, here's the code.

Here's the [images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yE0J.jpg) I am using

```
import pygame, time, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class playerClass(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("player.png").convert()
        self.image.set_alpha(196)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.y = 260
        self.rect.x = 500
    def update(self):
        pass

class bulletClass(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, speed, starty):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("bullet.png").convert()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.y = starty
        self.rect.x = 0
        self.speed = speed
    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.speed

gameExit = False
player = playerClass()
bullet1 = bulletClass(7,265)
bullet2 = bulletClass(10,295)
bullet3 = bulletClass(7,325)
bulletSprites = pygame.sprite.RenderPlain((bullet1, bullet2, bullet3))
playerSprites = pygame.sprite.RenderPlain((player))

bulletRectList = [bullet1.rect, bullet2.rect, bullet3.rect]

while not gameExit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

    screen.fill((255,255,255))

    bulletSprites.update()
    bulletSprites.draw(screen)

    playerSprites.update()
    playerSprites.draw(screen)

    collidedBulletList = player.rect.collidelistall(bulletRectList)

    if len(collidedBulletList) > 0:
        for i in collidedBulletList:
            print(i)


    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(10)
```

In this code, if you want to add a bullet just declare a new object

```
bullet4 = bulletClass(speed, yCoordinateToBeginWith)
```

and append it to bulletSprites and the bulletRectList and you are done. Using sprites simplifies this. Making your code sprite friendly would be difficult at the beginning but appending it is definitely easy afterwards.